# How to add small ramp or level painted concrete?

Tags: cement, slope

I have a small patio (10'x6') with painted (*oil based*) concrete.

It has a slightly uneven slope resulting in standing water with heavy rain.

I would like to add a small ramp/slope to the top of the patio.

Can I pour a new layer of concrete over the old painted layer with a new slope?

Comment: Not unless it's either substantial enough to be robust as an independent layer, or if it's a material designed to be used in a thin sheet. However, that patio's small enough that I'd consider raising it. A few levers would lift one side, and you could backfill with sand to a new level.